# Why is my TFT screen blurry?

Tags: windows-7, tft

I got 3 refurbished PC+TFT 19". All TFT shows a very blurry image. I estimate the TFT's are 2-3 yrs old. The PC's running Windows7 Pro. The resolution is set to the TFT native values.

It could be possible that all TFT's are broken but I have similiar models that are up to 5 yrs old, without any issue. I still think it could be a config issue but from the hardware it is possible that a TFT get broken I shows up a very blurry image.

*Update*

TFT HP 2035, grafic Intel Q35/GMA 3100, analog D-SUB connector, Manuf. date Sep 2005.

Config. resolution 1600x1200, PPP 150%

Without ClearType it is worst.

Desktop Icon titles seems to be good and clear. But in Notepad for example the effect is that on the right of the characters is a pinky shadow.

Comment: Are you running them at a non native resolution?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the post to native values, native resolution.

Comment: What exact model are they and what resolution are you running them on?

Comment: In addition have you tried running the cleartype tuner? might be incorrect settings

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, a photo could help.

Comment: Well, if its one thing and not the other, chances are it may be bad cleartype settings - the symptoms you're talking about point at it. I'd probably pop one of those on a system running another OS to see if *everything* at all looks bad. I'd also try it with DVI-I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments "Desktop Icon titles seems to be good and clear. But in Notepad for example the effect is that on the right of the characters is a pinky shadow." I'm guessing its bad cleartype settings - you may want to run "Adjust Cleartype Text" from the control panel, run through the wizard and see if it makes a difference.

It might also be cables - I'd try switching them, or running off DVI

Comment: I ran again thru the TFT's and one seems to be definetly broken, shades all around. The others are reasonable good. I will ask for substitution as they are in warrenty already. Thank you.

Comment: No, it were the brand new, but low cost cables.

Comment: Edited to reflect that then, since it *was* in the comments